# VB.net Trim string using position of a specific characters count

Tags: vb.net

I have some specific strings which have varying lengths of different content in each specific section. The field delimiter is the pipe `|` character. I'd like to remove everything including the 3rd appearance of the vertical bar character to the end of the string. Can anyone provide me any tips on what I would be looking for when trying to set this up? Thanks.

Ex:

```
| First text section | Second text section | Remove this group including the direct prior vertical bar | fourth group
```

Comment: No idea about vb.net, but instead of string operations I would suggest to split by `|` into an array, remove unwanted elements and then finally `join` again with `|` as glue.

Comment: Thank you @udondan I completely forgot about splitting then rejoining. That really helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Split function to divide the string into an array of strings, each element being the text between "|". Then append the first three array elements. You may need to remove some blanks before appending the strings.

```
Dim ss() As String
ss = InputString.Split("|")
outputstring = ss(0) & ss(1) & ss(2)
```

If you need to leave the vertical bars, you can insert them between elements in the last statement: `outputstring =  "|" & ss(0) & "|" & ss(1) & "|" &  ss(2)`, or you can use a sequence of Indexof and Substring:

```
i = inputstring.IndexOf("|")
i = inputstring.IndexOf("|", i + 1)
i = inputstring.IndexOf("|", i + 1)
outputstring = inputstring.Substring(0, i - 1)
```

In either method you should check to make sure there are enough vertical bars in the input string, to prevent an error.

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helped. I completely forgot about splitting and rejoining them together.